# Why the source order matters on working with multiple media sources in a single AVFormatContext?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libav, blackmagic-design, decklink

`avformat_open_input()` deletes the `AVFormatContext*` and returns `-6` when the source order changes.

I am trying to open multiple media sources dynamically with different(mixed) formats and codecs in a single context (`AVFormatContext`).

My media sources are a BlackMagic DeckLink Duo SDI input as first source and an `mp4 file` or `rtsp stream` as second.

When I order to open (`avformat_open_input()`) the source 2 (RTSP or MP4 file) at first and then open the BlackMagic DeckLink Duo, proceed as expected.

But when I change the order, and first open the DeckLink and then try to open RTSP stream or MP4 file, as I inspected in the step debugger; `AVFormatContext*` deleting in the `av_open_input()` function and it returns `-6` as result.

Please find the simple error reproduction code snappet below;

```
AVFormatContext* context{avformat_alloc_context()};
const char* url_source1{"DeckLink Duo (1)"};
const AVInputFormat* format_source1{av_find_input_format("decklink")};

const char* url_source2{"http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"};

// Open the first media input
int result = avformat_open_input(&context, url_source1, format_source1, NULL);

if(result < 0) {
  exit(1);
}

// Open the second media input
// This function in current order deletes the context and returns -6
result = avformat_open_input(&context, url_source2, NULL, NULL);
if(result < 0) {
  exit(1);
}

// Since the context has been deleted in previous step, segmentation fault accours here!
result = avformat_find_stream_info(context, NULL);
if(result < 0) {
  exit(1);
}

std::cout << "Total number of streams: " << context->nb_streams << std::endl;
```

But When I change the order and call the `avformat_open_input()` first for the `mp4` file and then the `DeckLink` device as following it proceed as expected, no error.

```
AVFormatContext* context{avformat_alloc_context()};
const char* url_source1{"DeckLink Duo (1)"};
const AVInputFormat* format_source1{av_find_input_format("decklink")};

const char* url_source2{"http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"};


// Open the second media input
int result = avformat_open_input(&context, url_source2, NULL, NULL);
if(result < 0) {
  exit(1);
}


// Open the first media input
result = avformat_open_input(&context, url_source1, format_source1, NULL);

if(result < 0) {
  exit(1);
}


result = avformat_find_stream_info(context, NULL);
if(result < 0) {
  exit(1);
}

std::cout << "Total number of streams: " << context->nb_streams << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly mentioned on the FFmpeg API `avformat_open_input()` will free the user-supplied context in case of failure:

```
ps (the first parameter) is a pointer to the user-supplied AVFormatContext (allocated by
avformat_alloc_context) may be a pointer to NULL, in which case an AVFormatContext is
allocated by this function and written into ps. Note that a user-supplied AVFormatContext
will be freed on failure.
```

Implement on your error handler an `av_strerror` to get human-readable error information. It will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have spotted the right point. 
Stringifying the error returns: "No such device or address". But it still does not clear to me how or why it works in reverse order.

Comment: Yes, that's strange. By the way, you can choose my answer as "Accepted Answer" too, if you like.